# JavaScript: Get date format from culture settings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date-format, cultureinfo, currentculture

I want to get Date format from my defined culture settings using JavaScript.
My Culture is defined in Web.config File as:

```
<globalization culture="en-GB"  uiCulture="en-GB"/>
```

I am getting the defined Culture through

```
CultureInfo culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
```

and i am passing it to my client. And at Client side I am using momemt.js library to parse my json date in to actual date format.

```
var date = moment(JsonDate).toDate().toLocaleDateString(myCulture); //"en-GB"
```

and I am getting the date in the required date format as `"16/07/2016"`
but I also want to get this Format as `dd/MM/yyyy` so that I can use this culture date format in my html (for date picker).

Please let me know how can I get this date format using culture info at client side.

Comment: did you find a solution so far ? I was thinking of having my own dictionary that store all the culture codes with it's date format

Answer (score 0):

You can use AngularJS-s date filter
check this link please - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0):

You may install moment.js in your project. https://momentjs.com/

Include moment-with-locales.min.js in your HTML template.

In your JavaScript:

```
moment.locale(myCulture);
var date = moment(JsonDate).format('L')
```